# UIImage not transparent png file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage, transparency

I have a simple png file. The image is that of a rectangle with a blue border and a transparent fill.

I'm adding this to my UIButton like so:

```
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomisationsBorder.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Why is it the transparency is not kept when I add it to my UIButton?

I have several buttons per page, and I don't want to have to create the normal state of the image and a selected state of the image..

Comment: Because UIButton also has its own alpha.

Comment: even if i adjust the alpha, it causes the entire button to fade.

Comment: Yeah, the entire button will fade when you decrease alpha of button.

Comment: Check these: 1) type of uibutton should be UIButtonTypeCustom   2) make a Project/Clean to make sure the proper image was sent to test device.   Also try to add for the state UIControlStateNormal to check everything is ok for the normal button state.

Comment: I've actually subclassed the button but now using a standard UIButton so I can change the type. That didn't work either. Cleaned and I have set the normal state of the UIButton [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NormalState.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: One way or the other you need to set the button background to transparent.  I forget the details -- you might get this "for free" with a custom button, but certainly not with a standard one.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS7 buttons render their image as mask, colorized with their tintColor. All non completely transparent pixels will be rendered in the Color. So make sure your inner fill is completely transparent or use:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected]
```

or make sure that the original image is rendered

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomisationsBorder.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
```

Comment: My image's fill is transparent. I can see the transparency in xcode when I view the image and I set the transparency in illustrator. But when it's on the simulator it's been filled white. 

UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I went with this solution for now. This code was available here and on a random blog somewhere.

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithBorderFromImage:(UIImage*)source {
    CGSize size = [source size];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [source drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *testImg =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return testImg;
}
```